# Dataflow job is failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to trigger a dataflow job to process a csv file then save the data into postgresql.
the pipeline is written in Java
this is my pipeline code:

```
public class DataMappingService {

DataflowPipelineOptions options;
Pipeline pipeline;

private String jdbcUrl;


private String DB_NAME;
private String DB_PRIVATE_IP;
private String DB_USERNAME;
private String DB_PASSWORD;
private String PROJECT_ID;
private String SERVICE_ACCOUNT;

private static final String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO upfit(upfitter_id, model_number, upfit_name, upfit_description, manufacturer, length, width, height, dimension_unit, weight, weight_unit, color, price, stock_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

public DataMappingService() {

    DB_NAME = System.getenv("DB_NAME");
    DB_PRIVATE_IP = System.getenv("DB_PRIVATEIP");
    DB_USERNAME = System.getenv("DB_USERNAME");
    DB_PASSWORD = System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD");
    PROJECT_ID = System.getenv("GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID");
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT = System.getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL");

    jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + DB_PRIVATE_IP + ":5432/" + DB_NAME;

    System.out.println("jdbcUrl: " + jdbcUrl);
    System.out.println("dbUsername: " + DB_USERNAME);
    System.out.println("dbPassword: " + DB_PASSWORD);
    System.out.println("dbName: " + DB_NAME);
    System.out.println("projectId: " + PROJECT_ID);
    System.out.println("service account: " + SERVICE_ACCOUNT);


    options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

    options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
    options.setProject(PROJECT_ID);

    options.setServiceAccount(SERVICE_ACCOUNT);
    options.setWorkerRegion("us-east4");
    options.setTempLocation("gs://upfit_data_flow_bucket/temp");
    options.setStagingLocation("gs://upfit_data_flow_bucket/binaries");
    options.setRegion("us-east4");
    options.setSubnetwork("regions/us-east-4/subnetworks/us-east4-public");
    options.setMaxNumWorkers(3);


}

public void processData(String gcsFilePath) {

    try {
        pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        System.out.println("pipelineOptions: " +pipeline.getOptions());
        pipeline.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(gcsFilePath))
                .apply("SplitLines", new SplitLines())
                .apply("SplitRecords", new SplitRecord())
                .apply("ReadUpfits", new ReadUpfits());
                .apply("write upfits", JdbcIO.<Upfit>write()
                        .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                                "org.postgresql.Driver", jdbcUrl)
                                .withUsername(DB_USERNAME)
                                .withPassword(DB_PASSWORD))
                        .withStatement(SQL_INSERT)
                        .withPreparedStatementSetter(new JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<Upfit>() {
                                                         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                                                         @Override
                                                         public void setParameters(Upfit element, PreparedStatement query) throws SQLException {
                                                             query.setInt(1, element.getUpfitterId());
                                                             query.setString(2, element.getModelNumber());
                                                             query.setString(3, element.getUpfitName());
                                                             query.setString(4, element.getUpfitDescription());
                                                             query.setString(5, element.getManufacturer());
                                                             query.setString(6, element.getLength());
                                                             query.setString(7, element.getWidth());
                                                             query.setString(8, element.getHeight());
                                                             query.setString(9, element.getDimensionsUnit());
                                                             query.setString(10, element.getWeight());
                                                             query.setString(11, element.getWeightUnit());
                                                             query.setString(12, element.getColor());
                                                             query.setString(13, element.getPrice());
                                                             query.setInt(14, element.getStockAmmount());
                                                         }
                                                     }
                        ));


        pipeline.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I have created a user managed service account as the documentation says: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#specifying_a_user-managed_worker_service_account and I'm providing the service account email in the pipeline options.
The service account has the following roles:

- roles/dataflow.worker
- roles/storage.admin
- iam.serviceAccounts.actAs
- roles/dataflow.admin
- Service Account Token Creator

when I upload the csv file, the pipeline is triggered but I'm getting the following error:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: Subnetwork https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-name/regions/us-east-4/subnetworks/us-east4-public is not accessible to Dataflow Service account or does not exist
```

I know that the subnetwork exists so I'm assuming its a permission error. The vpc network is created by my organization as we're not allowed to create our own.

Comment: this seems to be something with IP whitelisting. whitelist the IPs for that region and try again OR use the parameters to pass the network. here is the link https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options#security_and_networking

Comment: it was actually a problem with the latest version of apache beam (v.35) . The latest version for some reason was not setting the service account to the job which was leading it to fail. downgrading the version to 30 solved the issue.